# Bootstrap 3 tab panes not switching

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

New to bootstrap and I am having trouble getting the nav nav-tab to switch the panes. The setup is as follows:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#section-1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section-2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section-3" data-toggle="tab">Section 3</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="section-1">
                <p>This is section # content</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="section-2">
                <p>This is section # content</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="section-3">
                <p>This is section # content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I must be overlooking something. If someone could advise i would be grateful.

Comment: I have check. this is working fine. I think, this code is correct.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out. I was linking to the script files in the wrong order.